FormBuilderDropdown items style
I am trying to remove the vertical padding inside the dropdown and to change the border radius of the highlight of the selected item. I am using the flutter_form_builder package.
Here's my current code:
FormBuilderDropdown<Experience>(
  name: 'experience',
  icon: AppIcon(
    PhosphorIconsRegular.caretDown,
    color: context.colorScheme.iconSecondary,
  ),
  elevation: 4,
  style: context.textTheme.text14Regular,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: context.colorScheme.borderPrimary,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRegular),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: context.colorScheme.borderPrimary,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRegular),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: context.colorScheme.borderPrimary,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRegular),
    ),
    isDense: true,
  ),
  items: Experience.values
      .take(Experience.values.length - 1)
      .map(
        (experience) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: experience,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Text(
              context.l10n.experiences_600(experience.name),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
)

Here's what it looks like:

And here's the visual I would like:

I have tried to change the theme, I have tried to wrap my item with a container and changing its Padding but it doesn't change anything visually. I've also tried wrapping it directly with a Padding widget but it doesn't work either. When I search for solutions, I find solutions that don't work with this package and I am using it for all the forms in my application so I would like to keep it if possible.

I think you need to use dropdown_below for your expected design. I have see flutter_form_builder package but in this package dropdown is above of the widget like this . you can refer my some answer as per expected design 1, 2. hope any one of these answer help to you. Best of Luck

InputDecoration has a contentPadding property. I would assign it EdgeInsets.zero and see if that works. The problem appears to be a default padding that needs to get set to zero.
Here is the example in the ReadMe for flutter_form_builder:
InputDecorator(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Select option",
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 0.0), // Change to EdgeInsets.zero
    border: InputBorder.none,
    errorText: field.errorText,
  ),
  child: Container(
    height: 200,
    child: CupertinoPicker(
      itemExtent: 30,
      children: options.map((c) => Text(c)).toList(),
      onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
        field.didChange(options[index]);
      },
    ),
  ),
);


You can wrap it inside ButtonTheme like:
ButtonTheme(
  alignedDropdown: true,
  child: FormBuilderDropdown()
)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
